# How to start all files of unit tests from one file using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have written unit testing of models of a Ruby on Rails app. I have tested all the spec files individually. Now I want to start all files from one file. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test all models files of specs by following way...

```
rspec --pattern spec/models/*_spec.rb --color
```

Comment: I think this is the best way, also, if you want to just run every spec in a directory you can just pass the directory name without the pattern, rspec will recognize what to execute.
If for some reason you want to include the files in one file, you can also just require everything but I strongly disagree with this